# draw arrow in cartesian plane correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows

I want to draw in a cartesian plan using `pgfplots` an arrow and corresponding perpendicular directed lines.

I've tried the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
      axis x line  = bottom,
      axis y line  = left,
      width        = .63\textwidth,
      height       = .63\textwidth,
      ymax         = 10,
      ymin         = 0,
      xmax         = 10,
      xmin         = 0,
    ]
    \node (source)      at (axis cs:0,0){};
    \node (destination) at (axis cs:6,5){};
    \node (y0)          at (axis cs:0,5){};
    \node (x0)          at (axis cs:6,0){};

    \draw[dashed] (y0)--(destination);
    \draw[dashed] (x0)--(destination);
    \draw[->]     (source)--(destination);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But result is not good, because lines and arrow head does not stay on the same position:

[image: Wrong plot]

How can I draw the arrow and directed lines correctly?

Comment: Nodes have a finite size. Try `\coordinate (destination) at (axis cs:6,5);` and the same thing for `source`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you make an answer so I can accept it?